# a question about closure of a set in metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

let $X$ be a metric space and $V \subseteq X$ an open set which seperates two subset $A$ and $B$ of $X$. Then there is an open set $U \subseteq X$ which seperates $A$ and $B$ and such that $\overline{U} \subseteq V$.

I have already proof that there is an open set $U$ but I cannot prove that $\overline{U} \subseteq V$, can someone explain how we can achieve $\overline{U} \subseteq V$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that an open set $V$ separates two subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$?

Comment: it's mean that the complement of V can be partitioned into two seperated set, one containing A and the other one containing B.

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in U$ and $U$ is open, then in a metric space $(X,d)$ there is some $r>0$ such that $B_d(x,r) \subseteq U$ by definition of openness in a metric space.

Now $V=B_d(x, s)$ with $s=\frac{r}{2}>0$ is open and the triangle inequality implies $\overline{V} \subseteq \{y: d(x,y) \le s\}$ and the latter set is a subset of $U$ again.

So apply this idea to your given $V$ when $V$ is non-empty, if $V$ is empty, take $U=\emptyset$ instead.

Comment: Hello @Henno Brandsma, can you explain how the triangle inequality because i am a bit lost in that part, the rest is clear, thanks for your help.

Comment: @TriPuji show that if $d(x,y)>s$ then $B(y, d(x,y)-s) \cap B(x,s)=\emptyset$ so that $y$ is not in the closure of that ball with radius $s$.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, i want to ask again, how do you show the latter set is a subset of $U$? From the definition the $y$ in latter set is in $V$ you have not shown that how can it be in $U$